# prepositional phrase in a sentence

Tags: passive-voice, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases

> 1. The flowers in the vase were arranged by the maid.
> 2. The flowers were arranged in the vase by the maid.
> 3. The flowers were arranged by the maid in the vase.

Which sentence is more meaningful?

Comment: In general, please provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like what you think each means and what you want to express.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider ambiguity when choosing word order. (And "meaningful" isn't the word I would use here.)

The third example,

> The flowers were arranged by the maid in the vase.

seems to suggest that there was some tiny maid in the vase, like a genie in a bottle, whose job it was to arrange flowers. I suspect that is not the case.

The phrasal subject of the sentence ("the flowers in the vase") is split in the above, and there lies the problem. Keep the entire subject together and you should be fine.

Number two is fine, but has a different stress (the vase). It attempts to focus attention on the location of the arranging, which is a perfectly valid thing to do if that is your intent. If you don't care to emphasize the location of the arranging, choose the first example.

Comment: The first example, "The flowers in the vase were arranged by the maid," is the more natural phrasing and makes the most sense to a native English speaker.

Comment: As I suggest in my last sentence.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to emphasize it without editing your good answer. I loved the "tiny maid in the vase" part. :-)